# OpenCV3.0 - Imgcodecs.imread returns empty file

Tags: android, opencv, imread

I am a newbie in OpenCV - using OpenCV310 on Android.

When I call **Imgcodecs.imread** on a file that exists, I always get an empty Mat.
Could someone help me, Please?

The code is:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(root, "1.jpg");
Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "File exists: " + file.exists());
Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "Trying to read: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
Mat BGRMat = Imgcodecs.imread(file.getAbsolutePath(),Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if(BGRMat.empty())
{
      Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "Failed, Empty! Details: " + BGRMat);
}
else
{
      Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "Success! Details: " + BGRMat);
}
```

The log I get is:

> 07-05 20:53:26.941 28555-28555/com.sunshine.spotdetector
>   E/SpotDetector: File exists: true 
> 07-05 20:53:26.941
>   28555-28555/com.sunshine.spotdetector E/SpotDetector: Trying to read:
>   /storage/emulated/0/1.jpg 
> 07-05 20:53:26.941
>   28555-28555/com.sunshine.spotdetector E/SpotDetector: Failed, Empty!
>   Details: Mat [ 0*0*CV_8UC1, isCont=false, isSubmat=false,
>   nativeObj=0x7f97b2a660, dataAddr=0x0 ]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. It was a silly mistake:
I forgot to add android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
so it was returning 0 sized Mat

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it is correct.